# how can get column value in row edit event of gridview

Tags: asp.net

This is my editing code in rowdatabound event.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
                {
                    DropDownList dl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("Sectionname");
                    comp.MEDIUM = Convert.ToString(e.Row.FindControl("Medium"));
                    comp.CLASSNAME = Convert.ToString(e.Row.FindControl("ClassName"));
                    comp.ACADAMICYEAR = Convert.ToString(e.Row.FindControl("AcademicYear"));
                    DataTable worktype = inter.bindsectionforgird(comp);
                    dl.DataSource = worktype;
                    dl.DataTextField = "SectionName";
                    dl.DataValueField = "SectionId";
                    dl.DataBind();
                }
            }
```

still I am not able to get the value of those fields.

Comment: In what event did you write this code ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to write your code in `RowDataBound` event

```
  void GridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {

if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
       // Write your code here           
   }

 }
```

And you can find your Grid's columns as

```
e.Row.FindControl("yourControlID")
```

You can see detail in
[MSDN reference 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx)
[MSDN reference 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.itemdatabound.aspx)
[CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8666/Practical-use-of-the-DataGrid-s-ItemDataBound-even)

Comment: Yes.I write the code rowbound event.but still i cannot get the value of the bound field of gridview.

Comment: first i wrote those code  rowediting. and then change the  code into rowdataboud event.